# Bootstrap Table Makes width perpotialal to cell content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>

<body>
  
  <!-- first table -->
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Really Lone Name</td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <!-- second table -->
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name2</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the first column is taking up way more space then the second one due to the fact that it contains a longer string, even though all the strings can easily fit in an equal width table.

Is there a way to force the columns to be the same width?

Comment: Did you try: `td { width: 50%; }`?

Comment: Assume I don't know how many columns there will be

Comment: @qwertymk Check out the Answer i posted, let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

Just add `table-layout:fixed !important;` to the `table` in your **CSS**

**Snippet**

```css
table
{
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>

<body>
  
  <!-- first table -->
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Dummy</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Really Lone Name</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <!-- second table -->
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name2</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**Updated:** Gave one more column to first table.

> **Note:** I know you might be knowing this but still, here i have applied this property directly to `table`(just for demo), i suggest you to not apply property directly to `table`, if done would change for all of the tables using same `css file`. Instead give class to that tables and apply property to that class.